# Algolia Javascript Front-end Client search - .clearCache only works the very first time then results are outdated and need to reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, algolia

I've been struggling with this issue for a few weeks now, where with my Ionic app, I have a simple "search" that I'm doing that has no text for the search and utilizes ONLY filters. I have Algolia synced with a Firebase server, via Nodejs script, in which when I Create/Update/Delete an entry in Firebase, it automatically updates that object in Algolia.

The problem is that when I update an object in Firebase from my app, I automatically make another call to Algolia in order to get the updated result set. However, when I do this, the updated result doesn't appear until a second time when I have to reload the results. It should do this once I update and reload, but it requires a second reload.

I should note that when I first load the results from Algolia then do a Create/Update/Delete operation, it will show correctly, but subsequent updates seem to vary, based on a race condition between Algolia and Firebase. I've tried adding a `setTimeout()` because I believe it may be related to this race issue. It would seem that the sync happens almost instantly, but even with a 500ms delay, it still runs into this issue with inconsistent results. If I increase the delay to at least 1500ms - 5000ms, it seems to work every single time, but that all depends on network connection. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Algolia's indexing operations are asynchronous and expose a `task` that you can wait for completion.

Basically this means that, while indexing is very fast, it's not instantly available.

You should also know that the Algolia JS client (you use in frontend) has a cache on by default, that you can clear with `clearCache` when the task has been finished.

read more in the [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/troubleshooting/why-are-my-objects-not-immediately-available-for-search-after-adding-them/) and [`waitTask`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/wait-task/)

Comment: Hey thanks for responding to me so quickly! When I use `clearCache`, it doesn't really seem to solve the problem. For using waitTask, I'm automatically syncing Firebase and Algolia so there's just an event listener for Firebase that waits for an update then does an update operation. There's no way to integrate `waitTask()` in my current nodejs implementation :/

Comment: I assume you could use `waitTask` anyway in the firebase event and then send the event to your frontend with a web socket for example.

I'd personally see the stale data as less of a problem though, in most of the cases it's not really critical